Does the data processing inequality "work backwards?"
The data processing inequality, at least in the form I learned it, is that if we have some Markov chain X -> Y -> Z, then $I(X;Z) \leq I(X;Y)$, where I(X;Y) represents the mutual information between distributions X and Y. In other words, if you have some noisy connection between X and Y, there is no way to post-process Y so that you end up with more information about X than Y already has. I was curious if this fact was also true for pre-processing? That is, is it always true that $I(X;Z) \leq I(Y;Z)$?

Maybe elaborate on $I$.

Hint : if $X \to Y \to Z$ is a Markov chain, then also $Z \to Y \to X$ is.

Taking Leonbloy's comment as a hint, I think the following argument suffices.
If $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ is a Markov chain, then so is $Z \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X$. But, this means we can use the Data Processing Inequality on this reversed Markov chain to get that $$ I(Z; X) \leq I(Z; Y).$$ Then, mutual information is symmetric, so $I(X;Z) \leq I(Y;Z)$ as desired.
